# Weird behavior like dynamic scoping in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, dynamic-scope

I have following code for testing:

```js
// Generated by CoffeeScript 2.2.3
(function() {
  var t, test;

  test = function() {
    var dynamic_scoped_function, nested_function, vairable_function;
    dynamic_scoped_function = function() {
      return console.log(`variable function value: ${vairable_function()}`);
    };
    vairable_function = function() {
      return "not in nested function";
    };
    nested_function = function() {
      var nested_caller;
      vairable_function = function() {
        return "in nested function";
      };
      nested_caller = function() {
        console.log("calling dynamic scoped function from nested...");
        return dynamic_scoped_function();
      };
      return {
        vairable_function,
        nested_caller
      };
    };
    return {
      dynamic_scoped_function,
      nested_function
    };
  };

  t = test();

  t.dynamic_scoped_function();

  t.nested_function().nested_caller();

}).call(this);
```

The result when running with node.js is

```
variable function value: not in nested function
calling dynamic scoped function from nested...
variable function value: in nested function
```

Which seems that when name `variable_function` is resolved in `dynamic_scoped_function`, it depends on the calling stack, but not statically resolved to the outer one as my expects.

In my opinion, this behavior is silly because I cannot foresee where will `dynamic_scoped_function` be called. Does this language designed to act like so? Or I just simply misunderstood something?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is convoluted and code no one should ever write but does what i would expect...

Comment: So you are surprise when you have a variable defined outside of a block and you set the value inside that block that it would get that value?

Comment: Change it to `var vairable_function` in `nested_function` so that you declare a new variable in that scope.

Comment: There is no dynamic scoping here. You are simply reassigning the value of a variable.

Comment: @epascarello for clear I use the same variable for presentation. What if when I refactoring `dynamic_scoped_function`, I happen to mistype a variable's name, which just exists in `nested_function`?

Comment: @Cowsay When you make mistakes, the program doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @Cowsay than you use a linter that requires all variable to be defined and used or use `const` where things can not be redefined and would cause an error.

Comment: This is a good reason to use `function funcname(){}` instead of `funcname = function(){}`

Comment: @epascarello He mistyped a variable and it happened to match a different, unwanted variable. So it's not an undefined variable that a linter would catch.

Comment: @Barmar but if it was declared with const and not var, but in the end of the day, there is no way to deal with the problem of people mistyping variables. lol

Answer (score 1):

Once you execute `nested_function`, it assigns a new function to the `vairable_function` [sic] variable. The variable is still the same, but it now hold a new value. This has the same effect:

```
t.nested_function();          // replaces vairable_function
t.dynamic_scoped_function();  // accesses the redefined vairable_function
```

Or much simplified:

```
var foo = 'bar';
console.log(foo);
foo = 'baz';
console.log(foo);
```